# How to Average Data, arriving in Intervals in Simulink

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink

I am new to Simulink. I want to do average of the incoming data(which is coming after some intervals) from one block. For Example, Continuous framed data of 42 samples is out from one block. Along with the framed data there is another output(tag) which tells that these frame/samples belong to which category. Tags are numbers from 1-6. The output is random. I want to average the same category data. Like the first frame is of cat1, then after 4 frames cat1 frame again comes. Now how should I average this new frame with the previous one? I want to do this for all the categories. Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be to implement an arraylist for each category. Initialize the list with NaNs and keep a counter for the last sample from each category. Using the mean function you can get the average of all measurements.

If you just want the average of the current frame and previous frame, you can simply do `mean([cat1(n1) cat1(n1+1)])` where cat1 is the arraylist for frames from category 1 and n1 is the index of the previous frame in cat1 .

If you want a weighted moving average for a "real time" implementation, create an average variable for each category (call it av1, av2, etc.) and compute `av1 = alpha*av1 + (1-alpha)*cat1(n1+1)` (where alpha is the weight assigned to the previous average (alpha<1) and cat1(n1+1) is the new measurement) whenever a cat1 frame comes in .

Comment: But if I initialize the array inside the Matlab S-function, then every time it enters the function the array will be reinitialized? 
It will not hold the previous values. 
I am trying to work on Dwork I am thinking that might help. Any suggestions?